# Extracting only required details from the website using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to search a product 'Printer' in search bar automatically and retrieve only the MFR number of the products of company named EPSON. But the output which I am getting is more than what I want! It is the complete content of that class.

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome( "C:\All\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe" )
driver.get('https://shop.techdata.com/searchall?b=1&kw=printer')
items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name( 'productResult' )

for i, item in enumerate(items):
    if 'EPSON' in item.text:
       print(i, item.text)
```

Expected output is

```
3 

C11CF75201
```

The example of (undesired) output of this code which I am getting is as shown :

```
3 EPSON WORKFORCE PRO WF-4740 - MULTIFUNCTION PRINTER (COLOR)
Multifunction printer - color - ink-jet - Legal (8.5 in x 14 in) (original)  
 A4/Legal (media) - up to 22 ppm (copying) - up to 24 ppm (printing) - 500 
 sheets 
- 33.6 Kbps - USB 2.0, LAN, Wi-Fi(n), USB host, NFC

TD#: 12710297

MFR#: C11CF75201

Status: Active

MSRP:
$299.99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace line

```
print(i, item.text)
```

with

```
print(i, item.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="productCodes"]/div[2]/span').text)
```

to get required output

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help that works but I want to get only C11CF75201 as shown in my output. I don't want MFR#. Can you please tell me how do I do that?

Comment: Hi, That worked. Thanks. And if I want to go to every page of my website and do that search  and then move to the next page till the last page. How should I do?

Comment: You can try loop like `while True: try: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="pageNavigation nextPage"]/a').click() except: break`

Comment: It is printing the same thing on every page. I think there's problem with my loop placement.

Comment: It might be connected with new page rendering delay. You might need to add some explicit wait to get new page content. Please create new ticket regarding this issue

Comment: Hi, Appreciate your help. I posted a new question. Please search this in stackoverflow search box>>>> Iterate webpages through selenium python.